# Is there any fix or workaround for Gack with Error ID: 622456132-619398 (-1311433241) related to `SurveyInvitation` object?

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, survey, salesforce-survey

I have very simple LWC inside Community page. Inside the page I have the following query, which seems to raise Internal Salesforce Error, but I don't understand why

This is the query

```
SELECT Survey.Name, CommunityId, CustomField1__c, CustomField2__c, InvitationLink, LastModifiedDat
FROM SurveyInvitation
WHERE CommunityId = :Network.getCommunityId()
```

This is the error message

> An internal server error has occurred Error ID: 622456132-619398
> (-1311433241)

[image]

This only happens with `SurveyInvitation` object, when any other objects are queried, everything is OK.

Does anyone has a clue why this might happen?

How can we avoid it?

Is there any fix or workaround for this one?

Comment: Most of us here do not have access to the system that tracks gacks. However, I will mention @ca_peterson, as he typically does respond to questions of this type when possible.

Comment: Can you share the OrgId, instance, and time of occurrence of error so I can check the logs to suggest? - Salesforce support

Comment: Does this error happen if you run a query in the query editor in the Developer Console or Workbench? `SELECT Survey.Name, CommunityId, CustomField1__c, CustomField2__c, InvitationLink, LastModifiedDat
FROM SurveyInvitation`? That could be an indication of the problem if that query succeeds there. Do you have everything enabled that needs to be in order to use that object too? Not familiar with surveys, just want to cover bases.

Comment: I will try the solution presented in @Patlatus answer and then check your comments

Comment: The solution provided worked for me, so I think there is no need to share org or instance Id. Thanks for help @Swetha.

Comment: @nbrown Can you login as Community User into workbench?

Comment: I don't think Community Users can access workbench @p-p. The reason I mentioned it is that oftentimes if it works in the workbench or developer console for admins, that means there is a security or permissions related component to the error much like the accepted answer reveals.

Comment: @nbrown In my case it is working fine for admin in both Admin Console and workbench, but doesn't work for Community user

Comment: @sfdcfox not finding this gack in the index, so not much extra I can add at the moment other than the normal "a gack is always a bug, even if the fix to the bug is just returning a proper error message". If this gets a support case filed for it let me know the #

Comment: Please let me know if you intend to log a case, or I will log one on the community's behalf. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I think my clients won't file a case for this one, since we have already figured out the culprit and the workaround

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the exactly same error, it happens when a `SurveyInvitation` record is shared to an user, but `Survey` itself is not.

It is easily to verify if this is the same error by removing the `InvitationLink` field from the query, in such case there is no error in that case.

This configuration issue can be solved in three different way:

1. Share related `Survey` record to the corresponding User, Group, Role or Territory.
2. Remove all sharing from this `SurveyInvitation` record from the user
3. Change the query to include `AND SurveyId IN ( SELECT Id FROM Survey)`, in this way it will filter out those `SurveyInvitation` records which parent `Survey` records are not shared to the current user

Try out this query, I believe it should work for you as well

```
SELECT CommunityId, InvitationLink, LastModifiedDate, Survey.Name
FROM SurveyInvitation
WHERE ((InviteExpiryDateTime = null OR InviteExpiryDateTime >= TODAY)
AND (CommunityId =: Network.getNetworkId())
AND SurveyId IN ( SELECT Id FROM Survey)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me!